# How to use -(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

i want to use - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request, to alert user that there is an error with the network ( it can not connect to the network) how i can recuper the error and implement this method,

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To implement this method, your classe should be the delegate of your request :

```
[request setDelegate:self];
```

Then the method will automatically be called if the request failed

```
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@", [request error]);
    if ([request error]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Fail." 
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;

    } 
}
```

Comment: ok thaks, but i want filter the errors, i want just detect the network erro,ASIConnectionFailureErrorType. thanks

Comment: So you test the `[request error]` and if it's an `ASIConnectionFailureErrorType` you display the `UIAlertView` else you just return

Comment: `if([[request error] code] == ASIConnectionFailureErrorType){ ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the delegate of ASIHTTPRequest by

```
request.delegate = self;
```

which will enable you to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply print the alert if error occurs using uialertView
thanks